# Finding the center of an image to define a hitbox

Tags: python, math, pygame

I'm trying to select the center of my image to make a hitbox some pixels around it. 
I was able to inflate() the hitbox to make it the right size, but it always uses the top left corner of the image. This is fine when i'm moving left, but when i turn right it goes away from the character (in the image the character is dragging a sword, so it goes way off center). 
I've been reading about Vector2, pos and offset, but i can't get it to work.

In conclusion i need to learn a way to find the center of my image in order to place it's hitbox a few pixels to each side.  Either that or how to "shift" the corner the hitbox uses so it's always in the front of the char.

Comment: I am not familiar with pygame, but in a general case if you divide the image width by 2 and the height by 2 that will get you the center coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) object. Get the rectangle from the [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object (`image`) and set the top left corner position (`x`, `y`) of the rectangle. e.g.:

```py
rect = image.get_rect()
rect.topleft = (x, y)
```

respectively

```py
rect = image.get_rect(topleft = (x, y))
```

[`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) provides a lot of virtual attributes, which can be used to retrieve the corners, borders, center and size of the rectangle. `.center` returns the center of the rectangle:

```py
center_x, center_y = rect.center
```

Comment: i've tried this but i still can't figure how to make it shift from one corner to the other. so when im going left it is perfect, but when i'm going right the hitbox only surrounds the sword... I'll try making a mask next and see how that goes. Thx